# TPL Data Flow Optimization

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a TPL dataflow set up in this manner:

1. Download byte array
2. Process data
3. Stream processed data to another location

This flow works great, but occasionally it runs into a backup while downloading file, connection hiccup, etc.  What I'd like to do is have parallel downloads but still ensure that step 3 is executed such that the receiving party gets the payload in the correct order.

```
var broadcaster = new BroadcastBlock<string>(d => d);


var downloader = new TransformBlock<string, byte[]>(async data => {
  // Download and return data       
});


var processor = new TransformBlock<byte[], byte[]> (async data => {
  // Process and return data
});


var uploader = new ActionBlock<byte[]>(async input => {
  // Upload file to another location
});


broadcaster.LinkTo(downloader);
downloader.LinkTo(processor);
processor.LinkTo(uploader);


broadcaster.SendAsync("http://someUrl");
broadcaster.SendAsync("http://someOtherUrl")
```

So in the above code snippet, I'd want the two urls to download simultaneously, but it's important that the first one gets processed by the uploader before the second url.  Can somebody point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Why even 3 transform blocks? Can't you just use one that performs the 3 steps sequentially?

Comment: Sure, but this is modular.  Besides, this is scaled back from the actual logic...

Comment: Ok but that would solve your problem I think. 3 helper functions are just as modular and less complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd want the two urls to download simultaneously, but it's important that the first one gets processed by the uploader before the second url

Then just set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` on that block and it will behave like this. When URLs 1 and 2 are being downloaded simultaneously and 2 completes before 1 does, it will still wait for 1 to complete before 2 is sent to the following block.

This might not be the most efficient approach, but it does ensure that the order of processing is maintained across all blocks in a pipeline.

Comment: Ah you're right!  I just assumed that as soon as the block was parallelized, that it'd only maintain the execution order of the blocks, not the order of the data being pushed through as well.

Comment: @user2339814 Yeah, it was surprising to me the first time I learned about this too.